# How to get facebook user's name,id and email with just it's facebook id? ( c++ )

Tags: c++, facebook, marmalade

I am using Marmalade with C++ and I need to get the Facebook user name, picture, and email and all I have is its Facebook user ID.

I am using this example and it all worked until now but I need a way to at least search or somehow get what I need because I really don't know what to do.

http://api.madewithmarmalade.com/ExampleS3EFacebook.html

Is there a way I'm not seeing to get the user name and picture or do I need some other class and Facebook stuff to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the marmalade framework, but what I know is that you can't get the email address from the user if you don't have a user access token with an enable `user_email` permission.

I guess you could use the `s3eFBRequest_WithGraphPath` method ([http://api.madewithmarmalade.com/group__facebookapigroup.html#gaca80d12f6a25a19619b222af6bc3d290](http://api.madewithmarmalade.com/group%5f%5ffacebookapigroup.html#gaca80d12f6a25a19619b222af6bc3d290)) to pass the following path:

```
/{user_id}?fields=name,picture
```

where {user_id} is your user_id.

Comment: I didn't understand, that method like constructs a request how can i use to get the username and picture i dont get it. And thanks for the answer i need to get this done ^^

Comment: Read the docs, like I said, I don't know the marmalade framework, but I think you can use Google to get more info like the following http://marmalade.cloud.answerhub.com/questions/7351/s3efacebook-retrieving-profile-icon-and-retrieving.html